# How to count number of items through JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have some items  and through Jquery I create a table of some entries. Now i want to count the number of items and show the value in the textbox.

This is my code:

```
$("#addToList").click(function (e) {
    debugger;
    e.preventDefault();

    if ($.trim($("#Stock_ID").val()) == "" || $.trim($("#AvailableQuantity").val()) == "" || $.trim($("#TransferQuantity").val()) == "")
        return;
    var productName = $("#Stock_ID option:selected").text();
    var pid = $("#Stock_ID option:selected").val();
    let availablequantity = $("#AvailableQuantity").val();
    let transferquantity = $("#TransferQuantity").val();
    let qtyTotal = 0;
    let detailsTableBody = $("#detailsTable tbody");
    var productItem = `<tr>
                            <td pid=${pid}><span data-stock_qty="${productName}" data-itemId="0" href="#" class="stockItem" >
                                ${productName}
                            </td>
                            <td><span data-line_qty="${availablequantity}" data-itemId="0" href="#" class="qtyItem" >${availablequantity}</span></td>

                            <td>${transferquantity}</td>
                            <td>${(parseFloat(availablequantity) - parseInt(transferquantity))}</td>
                           <td><a data-line_total="${(parseFloat(availablequantity) - parseInt(transferquantity))}" data-itemId="0" href="#" class="deleteItem">Remove</a></td>
                        </tr>`;

    detailsTableBody.append(productItem);
    clearItem();
    $('.stockItem').each(function () { qtyTotal = qtyTotal + parseInt($(this).data("stock_qty")); });
    $('.totalquantity').val(qtyTotal);
});
```

This is my output:

[image: screenshot]

You can see that Total Stock Count is showing Nan. I want to show total stock Count there. That would be 4.

Comment: The attribute name in the HTML should be `data-stock-qty` not `data-stock_qty`

Comment: Looks like you put the product name (some string) in the `data-stock_qty`, but not the quantity (some number).

Comment: Yes you are correct product name in string.and i need to count that and show in textbox.

Comment: Try replacing this line: `$('.stockItem').each(function () { qtyTotal = qtyTotal + parseInt($(this).data("stock_qty")); });` with this line: `qtyTotal = $('.stockItem').length;`

Comment: Its working !!!!!!!!!!!!!!. I really appreciate for this. Thank you so much.